# Не читается файл

Tags: python

Не читается файл(.txt). Ничего не выводит, код просто останавливается. Вот код:

```
f = open("Безназвания.txt")
for line in f:
    line
```

Текст из файла:

```
Hello, World!
some text
```

p.s.: Работаю на макбуке, может это влияет?
p.p.s: Новичок в Python(Занимаюсь чуть больше 2-х месяцев, код скопировал с одного сайта

Comment: может вместо `line` написать `print(line) `

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код заработает, если вы сразу запустите его в интерпретаторе:

```
~/IdeaProjects/PJob @ mac(x): python3
Python 3.7.6 (default, Dec 30 2019, 19:38:28) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open("Безназвания.txt")
>>> for line in f:
...     line
... 
'Hello, World!\n'
'some text\n'
```

Если же хотетите запускать python3 code.py, нужно использовать `print(line)`

Answer (score 0):

Объясню подробно:
Вы записываете просто `line` что возвращает значение этой переменной,а не выводит ее.Для вывода используется метод `print()`, это вы должны знать.Соответственно код должен быть таким:

```
f = open("Безназвания.txt")
for line in f:
    print(line)
```